# How can I save these same variable names into a mySQL column using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How can I save the below

```
cv_skills=MySQL&cv_skills=HTML&cv_skills=AutoCAD
```

as

```
MySQL,HTML,AutoCAD
```

into the `cv_skills` column of my mySQL database?

Currently I am doing `implode` but it does not work

```
$cv_skills = mysql_real_escape_string(implode( ',', $_POST["cv_skills"]));
```

**In this question I have shown the variables as GET just to show how are passed. I am using POST for sure :)**

Comment: `cv_skills=MySQL&cv_skills=HTML&cv_skills=AutoCAD` that implies a GET and you're using POST in the query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, I know. I posted it this way to make known how the variables are passed.

Comment: Don't they overwrite and you get only `AutoCAD` ?

Comment: what about the query to INSERT/UPDATE? maybe that's failing you. Are you using `mysql_` to connect with also?

Comment: @VasilShaddix unfortunately, yes. only the last is saved.

Comment: oh hold on. As a few said, you're overwriting your query here using the same parameters. Use different ones `cv_skills1=MySQL&cv_skills2=HTML&cv_skills3=AutoCAD` - *"I am using POST for sure"* then show us your HTML form that goes with this.

Comment: if you're using a form with this (which I suspect contains `name="cv_skills"` for multiple fields and didn't assign them as arrays such as  `name="cv_skills[]"` and not using a `foreach` and not using a post method, then that could be the reason. It's unknown because you haven't show us enough (PHP) code and for the query itself. I'm guessing here.

Comment: you have been given answers below now. I am out of the loop. Wishing you well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to change the way you are passing the `cv_skills` variable. Change to an array for example `cv_skills[]=HTML&cv_skills[]=AutoCAD;` etc.

I would suggest using `json_encode($_POST['cv_skills'])` to save it with the exact same name. And then pass it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

In the current way that you pass the variables to your PHP script they will just get continuously overridden. If you change the variable to the following

```
cv_skills[]=MySQL&cv_skills[]=HTML&cv_skills[]=AutoCAD
```

you can then access the data like this

```
$_POST['cv_skills'][0] == 'MySQL'
$_POST['cv_skills'][1] == 'HTML'
$_POST['cv_skills'][2] == 'AutoCAD'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reusing field names you cannot take values from PHP superglobals. Instead, you need to parse request body manually.

You can read raw POST data from the `'php://input'` wrapper [[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)]. Parsing the string is trickier; you can use a combination of [explode()](http://php.net/explode) and [rawurldecode()](http://php.net/rawurldecode).

As about the database, explaining how to interact with MySQL is way beyond the scope of this site. I can only suggest you have a look at [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and get a reasonably recent book (`mysql_real_escape_string()` does not even exist any more in latest PHP versions).